# Treasure Hunter and Arrive effects

Tags: clank

In its body text, the Treasure Hunter card says (emphasis in original):

> **Replace a card in the dungeon row.** *(If the new card has a dragon attack symbol, ignore it.)*

If the replacement card has Arrive text (for example, the Overlord which says “ARRIVE All players get +1 Clank!”), does that effect still occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [BoardGameGeek thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1770280/questions-arrive-effects) they ask the same question.

> 2. Do Arrive effects trigger when replaced with the companion that replaces a card in the dungeon row? That card mentions that Dragon attacks are ignored, but doesn't say anything about Arrive effects, so could go both ways.

Where Sylvain Gauthier answered:

> Arrive effects always take place no matter when the card is drawn from the deck.
> Dragon attack, on the other hand, are reshuffled in the deck during initial set up and doesn't take effect when certain companions are played.(Will be specified on that companion's text box)

So an on arrive effect always takes place even when the card is replaced by the Treasure Hunter card.